# Is there a way to detect when a popup window appears in Android

Tags: java, android

I started a project of a windows program that connects to an android phone and gives the user information
about it, so I want to display all of the popups that appere on the phone. to do this I need the app version of the program to catch them somehow and give me the name of the app that sent the popup and the popup's contant. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be kind of security issue if any app could do that... you can try with `AccessibilityService` with some permissions for reading screen/running Activities and checking style of every `Activity` is this "popup", but note that some of them are just `DialogFragment`s. So I doubt you can recognize "popups" this way in a reliable way. Look for `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED` for more info

Comment: thank you for replaying.
after I find an `AccessibilityEvent` would it be possible to read it or would it be a security
issue?

Comment: well, you need special permission from user to do such recognition (to be precise: service must be enabled manually in device Settings, you can only pass user there, can't enable programmatically). So if user will agree for this `AccessiblityService` run then there is no security issue (Android allows that, user agreed). I'm just not shure if you can achieve your purposes with this method, my answer is just a hint ;)

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful :) good luck!